# 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2012, x86, 64-bit, processor

I have a web project built in Visual Studio 2012. Its using the Oracle.DataAccess.dll 
Now the one I see in my solution is 4.121 version. But am receiving this error where the project is looking for 2.122 version.
Thanks for your help in advance

Below is the stack trace

> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.122.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/TFS/IVAS/CPTSBaselineCode/FrontEndApplications/CampaignPerformanceTracking/CampaignPerformanceTracking/
>   LOG: Initial PrivatePath =
>   C:\TFS\IVAS\CPTSBaselineCode\FrontEndApplications\CampaignPerformanceTracking\CampaignPerformanceTracking\bin
>   Calling assembly : Aarp.Cpts.DataObjects, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file:
>   C:\TFS\IVAS\CPTSBaselineCode\FrontEndApplications\CampaignPerformanceTracking\CampaignPerformanceTracking\web.config
>   LOG: Using host configuration file:  LOG: Using machine configuration
>   file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Post-policy reference: Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.122.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342 LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/XXX/AppData/Local/Temp/1/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/vs/ecf130a4/7d736bb0/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL. LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/XXX/AppData/Local/Temp/1/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/vs/ecf130a4/7d736bb0/Oracle.DataAccess/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/TFS/IVAS/CPTSBaselineCode/FrontEndApplications/CampaignPerformanceTracking/CampaignPerformanceTracking/bin/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
>   WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major
>   Version ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040).
>   Probing terminated.

Stack Trace:

> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.122.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>   CampaignPerformanceTracking.JobSearch..ctor() in
>   c:\TFS\IVAS\CPTSBaselineCode\FrontEndApplications\CampaignPerformanceTracking\CampaignPerformanceTracking\JobSearch.aspx.cs:25
>   ASP.jobsearch_aspx..ctor() in
>   c:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\1\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\ecf130a4\7d736bb0\App_Web_xghf0hzg.3.cs:0
>   __ASP.FastObjectFactory_app_web_xghf0hzg.Create_ASP_jobsearch_aspx() in c:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\1\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\ecf130a4\7d736bb0\App_Web_xghf0hzg.4.cs:0
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildResultCompiledType.CreateInstance() +31
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp) +100
>   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context,
>   String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +31 
>   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.System.Web.IHttpHandlerFactory2.GetHandler(HttpContext
>   context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String
>   physicalPath) +64
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String
>   requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean
>   useAppConfig) +191
>   System.Web.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +156    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit difficult to help you if we see only the error message and nothing else. Some points:

- Which version of .NET framework did you set in your compile options? If you set 3.5 or lower then your application tries to load Oracle.DataAccess.dll 2.xxx. If you set 4.0 or higher then Oracle.DataAccess.dll 4.xxx will be loaded.
- The architecture (i.e. 32-bit or 64-bit) of Oracle.DataAccess.dll must be the same as the architecture if your application
- Did you install Oracle.DataAccess.dll (Oracle Data Provider for .NET)? - it is not included in Oracle Instant Client by default.
- Version of `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` must be **exactly** the same version as your Oracle Client
- Oracle installer 12.1 or newer does not add `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` to GAC. You must add it manually.

Comment: Adding Oracle.DataAccess.dll to GAC did the trick for me. Thanks much! C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools>gacutil /i "D:\app\client\sys_t72auto\product\19.0.0\client_1\ODP.NET\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll"